# Uniquely divisible neighborhoods of identity in topological groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups

Let $G$ be a (finite dimensional real) Lie group, and let $A\subset G$ be an open neighborhood of identity. If $A=\operatorname{Exp}(\mathcal{A})$ is the injective range of the exponential map from a star-shaped neighborhood $\mathcal{A}\subset\mathcal{G}$ of the origin in the Lie algebra $\mathcal{G}$ of $G$, then $A$ is a uniquely divisible neighborhood of identity, i.e., $\exists!\sqrt[m]{x}\in A$ for all $x\in A$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

**Question:** Given a locally compact Hausdorff topological group $G$, is it always possible to find an open uniquely divisible neighborhood of identity in $G$? If no, then what are the necessary/sufficient conditions?

If $G$ is discrete the question seems to trivialize, so let's assume $G$ is non-discrete. If $G$ is not Lie then I think it needs to have non-trivial subgroups in every neighborhood of identity, but I am not sure this is related.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is very false for groups like the $p$-adic numbers, the profinite completion of the integers, etc etc.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that saying "question is very false" you mean that the statement in the question is far from being true (did you mean something else?). The examples you brought are totally disconnected, aren't they? I guess it is difficult to find small open subsets at all in those topologies, hence the problem. Thanks for pointing this out (again, if I have understood your assertion correctly).

Comment: Heh, I guess for the $p$-adic numbers one could use the $p$-adic numbers themselves :-) so maybe the $p$-adic integers are a better example. Yes, I just mean that in my mind your question is ludicrous because if you asked me to think of a locally compact Hausdorff topological group then because of my background the first 5 examples I'd think of would not satisfy your question.

Comment: @znt "unlikely" might be more useful than "ludicrous"... ?

Comment: Possibly a more reasonable question is whether this condition characterizes Lie groups among locally compact groups.

Comment: Maybe that would be more reasonable, maybe not. I don't know. It depends on the class of groups (which I don't know) where the answer is positive. If the class is not too far from that of Lie groups than you are right. But I know nothing that would make me believe in that. Do you have a good argument for that?

Comment: @YCor: As mentioned by znt, the additive group of the $p$-adic field $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is uniquely divisible, but is not a Lie group. Does it help to add the conditions that the neighborhood can be taken arbitrarily small, and that the neighborhood is closed under taking $m$th roots?

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed necessary (for my purposes) that the neighborhood be closed under taking roots. I should have made this more explicit in the question; will edit now. Regarding the neighborhood being arbitrarily small, that's certainly another interesting question, but for my purposes a single uniquely divisible neighborhood suffices - even if it's the whole group. Another question is whether imposing the existence of arbitrarily small neighborhoods in the given topology (which rules out totally disconnected groups) will already guarantee a positive answer. I don't know.

Comment: Right: I guess that the property in its "arbitrary small neighborhood" version characterizes Lie groups. For totally disconnected groups, I'm aware of nilpotent examples... In general, one can pick a uniquely divisible neighborhood $N$, a compact open subgroup $K$ contained in $N$, and consider the set $V$ of elements of $N$ having a positive power in $K$. Then $V$ is open and uniquely divisible. We can wonder whether $V$ is contained in a locally elliptic subgroup: I don't know.